# How did West Germanic languages evolve?

Tags: historical-linguistics, reference-request, indo-european, germanic-languages, evolution

I'm trying to make a comprehensive phylogenetic tree of Germanic languages, with dates of divergence, and I have been unable to find details on West Germanic languages and how they diverged. I have found terms such as Ingvaeonic, Istvaeonic, and Irminonic, but's it's been difficult to determine how exactly West Germanic languages developed into the plethora of languages and dialects that exist today (as well as extinct languages).

I'm specifically interested in the time periods of the changes. I'm looking for something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_languages#Diachronic), but with more exact dates. I've seen trees like [this](http://www.hum.uit.no/a/svenonius/lingua/history/Image2.gif), but many of them seem to have some key differences, like how exactly Dutch is related to English. I think a lot of this stems from simplifications, and I'm looking for the most comprehensive diagram possible that can show how West Germanic languages are related to each other.

Comment: It would help if you could [edit] this to explain what you already have and what information you still need. Do you need more detail than Wikipedia's tree? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Germanic_languages#Family_tree

Comment: You do understand that there is no accurate dating possible, right? Not because we don't have enough data, but because one would claim "This and that are different languages", while others would not agree to that until much later in the language's split.